# KnexJS with multiple tables and aliases

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I've been playing with KnexJS lately and I've got most of what I need from KnexJS documentation, however I have a bit more complex MySQL query that I can't 'port' on my own to Knex. I know there's an option to use `.raw()`, however I'd like to avoid that if possible.

My working MySQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT A.profile_id, C.model_name, D.brand_name, A.car_plate
FROM carsdb.profiles_has_cars A,
     carsdb.profiles B,
     carsdb.brands_cars C,
     carsdb.brands D
WHERE A.profile_id = B.user_id AND
      A.car_id = C.id AND
      A.brand_id = D.id;
```

What I got so far is:

```
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db({
      A: "profiles_has_cars",
      B: "profiles",
      C: "brands_cars",
      D: "brands"
    })
      .select("A.profile_id", "C.model_name", "D.brand_name", "A.car_plate")
      .where({
        "A.profile_id": userId,
        "A.car_id": "C.id",
        "A.brand_id": "D.id"
      })
      .then(results => {
        if (results > 0) {
          resolve(results);
        } else {
          reject("There is a problem with a query");
        }
      });
  });
```

I've also tried using an object as an argument in `.where()`, but that didn't do anything either.

Any help or suggestion?

Comment: Can you specify your problem? It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Well it doesn't work as it is. Code always returns a reject from promise because there are no results produced from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I've got it. `knex` doesn’t understand that `.where` values are actually references to another fields and interpret them as strings.

Try to replace such with one more for each `.whereRaw("A.car_id = C.id")`. (For references only, not for actual values).

Comment: While this indeed works, it returns duplicates for each row. I didn't notice that earlier. How would I 'chain' multiple `where`? Like this:

`      .where("A.profile_id", userId)
      .andWhereRaw("A.car_id = C.id")
      .andWhereRaw("A.brand_id = D.id")`

Comment: and can be omitted. whereRaw works the same as andWhereRaw

Comment: I use this for debugging: `const builder = knex('tablename').where(...); console.log(builder.toString()); builder.then(...);`

Comment: Yeah thanks for the tip. Turns out there was a problem with my MySQL query. I've added `.distinct()` and it fixed the issue.